# Why a background ssh can take over the tty from Bash?

Tags: bash, ssh, pty, job-control, process-group

(I'm using Bash 4.4.12 on Debian 8. Question also asked in the [bash mailing list](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2017-06/msg00092.html).)

See the following steps to reproduce the problem.

From **tty #1** (`pts/2`):

```
[STEP 101] # tty
/dev/pts/2
[STEP 102] # ssh -o ControlMaster=yes -o ControlPath=/tmp/socket.ssh -N -f 127.0.0.1
[STEP 103] # ps -C ssh u
USER        PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root       1390  0.0  0.0  36440   656 ?        Ss   11:33   0:00 ssh -o ControlMaster=yes -o ControlPath=/tmp/so
[STEP 104] #
[STEP 105] # ssh -o ControlMaster=no -o ControlPath=/tmp/socket.ssh \
             127.0.0.1 sleep 3600 &
[1] 1396
[STEP 106] #    <-- Here I cannot input anything except <CTRL-C>
```

*STEP 102* started the multiplexed SSH connection running as a daemon. *STEP 105* tries to use the multiplexed connection to run a `sleep` command. But then I cannot input anything into the current shell. If I kill the `ssh ... sleep &` process then Bash will be able to accept my input again. Seems like all input is consumed by the background `ssh` process.

Go to **tty #2** (`pts/3`):

```
[STEP 201] # tty
/dev/pts/3
[STEP 202] # ps t pts/2 j
  PPID    PID   PGID    SID TTY       TPGID STAT   UID   TIME COMMAND
   723   1353   1353   1353 pts/2      1353 Ss+      0   0:00 bash
  1353   1396   1396   1353 pts/2      1353 S        0   0:00 ssh -o ControlMaster=no -o ControlPath=/tmp/socket.ssh 127.0.0.1 sleep 3600
[STEP 203] # ps s 1396
  UID    PID  PENDING  BLOCKED  IGNORED    CAUGHT STAT TTY    TIME COMMAND
    0   1396 00000000 00000000 00001000 188004003 S    pts/2  0:00 ssh -o ControlMaster=no -o ControlPath=/tmp/socket.ssh 127.0.0.1 sleep 3600
[STEP 204] #
```

I decoded the sig masks:

```
PENDING (00000000):
BLOCKED (00000000):
IGNORED (00001000):
  13 PIPE
CAUGHT (188004003):
   1 HUP
   2 INT
  15 TERM
  28 WINCH
  32
  33
```

Here we can see the ssh process does not catch the `SIGTTIN` signal. That's what confuses me because a background job (process group) should receive `SIGTTIN` and be stopped when it attempts to read from the tty.

Comment: What happens when when you try <CTRL>+Z?

Comment: Just tried. Nothing would happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've figured out what's happening. Let me explain it.

From **tty #1** (`pts/2`):

```
[STEP 300] # tty
/dev/pts/2
[STEP 301] # ssh -o ControlMaster=yes -o ControlPath=/tmp/socket.ssh -N -f 127.0.0.1 < /dev/null >& /dev/null
[STEP 302] # ps -C ssh j
 PPID   PID  PGID   SID TTY      TPGID STAT   UID   TIME COMMAND
    1  4052  4052  4052 ?           -1 Ss       0   0:00 ssh -o ControlMaster=yes -o ControlPath=/tmp/socket.ssh -N -f 127.0.0.1
[STEP 303] # ls -l /proc/4052/fd/
total 0
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 2017-06-12 22:59 0 -> /dev/null
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 2017-06-12 22:59 1 -> /dev/null
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 2017-06-12 22:59 2 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 2017-06-12 22:59 3 -> socket:[370151]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 2017-06-12 22:59 4 -> socket:[370201]
[STEP 304] # ssh -o ControlMaster=no -o ControlPath=/tmp/socket.ssh 127.0.0.1 sleep 3600 &
[1] 4062
[STEP 305] #    <-- Cannot input anything
```

Go go **tty #2** (`pts/3`):

```
[STEP 401] # tty
/dev/pts/3
[STEP 402] # ps t pts/2 j
 PPID   PID  PGID   SID TTY      TPGID STAT   UID   TIME COMMAND
  579  3552  3552  3552 pts/2     3552 Ss+      0   0:00 bash
 3552  4062  4062  3552 pts/2     3552 S        0   0:00 ssh -o ControlMaster=no -o ControlPath=/tmp/socket.ssh 127.0.0.1 sleep 3600
[STEP 403] # ls -l /proc/4062/fd/    # The `ssh ... sleep' process
total 0
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 2017-06-12 23:00 0 -> /dev/pts/2
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 2017-06-12 23:00 1 -> /dev/pts/2
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 2017-06-12 23:00 2 -> /dev/pts/2
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 2017-06-12 23:00 3 -> socket:[370349]
[STEP 404] # ls -l /proc/4052/fd/    # The `ssh -o ControlMaster=yes' process
total 0
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 2017-06-12 22:59 0 -> /dev/null
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 2017-06-12 22:59 1 -> /dev/null
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 2017-06-12 22:59 2 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 2017-06-12 22:59 3 -> socket:[370151]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 2017-06-12 22:59 4 -> socket:[370201]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 2017-06-12 23:02 5 -> socket:[370350]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 2017-06-12 23:02 6 -> /dev/pts/2
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 2017-06-12 23:02 7 -> /dev/pts/2
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 2017-06-12 23:02 8 -> /dev/pts/2
[STEP 405] #
```

*STEP 403*'s output shows that the `ssh ... sleep` process' *stdin/stdout/stderr* are opened on `pts/2`. This is normal.

But *STEP 404*'s output (compared to *STEP 303*) shows that the `ssh -o ControlMaster=yes` process is also opening `pts/2`. I believe this is how the multiplexed SSH works — the new `ssh ... sleep` process passes its open file descriptors to the `ssh -o ControlMaster=yes` process through the UNIX domain socket (`-o ControlPath=/tmp/socket.ssh`). So it's actually the `ssh -o ControlMaster=yes` process that's consuming all input from `pts/2`. And since the `ssh -o ControlMaster=yes` process is not in the same process session as the `bash` process (and `ssh ... sleep`) so the job control mechanism does not apply to it even it's running in background (as a daemon) and reading from the `pts/2`.

Put it another way: `SIGTTIN` is only sent to a process which runs as a background job and tries to read from its *controlling terminal*. Here the `ssh -o ControlMaster=yes` process is running in background but it's not a job of the `bash` *process session* and it does not have a *controlling terminal* at all.

---

A bit more about passing FDs between processes through the UNIX domain sockets (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket)):

> In addition to sending data, processes may send file descriptors across a *Unix domain socket* connection using the `sendmsg()` and `recvmsg()` system calls. This allows the sending processes to grant the receiving process access to a file descriptor for which the receiving process otherwise does not have access.